# What is the correct format to input a date parameter in an Oracle database from c#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, ora-06550

This is the error message I am getting

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OBPL_SU_PLAN_UPDATE_PLAN_DTLS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Code:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "CWPCDS.OBPL_SU_PROCESS_PKG.OBPL_SU_PLAN_UPDATE_PLAN_DTLS";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_PLAN_DETAIL_ID", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = detailId; 
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_PLAN_USER_DETAIL_ID", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = null; 
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_TRANSACTION_PLAN", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 20).Value = null;
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_PLAN_REV_ID", OracleDbType.Int64).Value = planRev;                   
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_TRANSACTION_TYPE", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 20).Value = transType;
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_PLAN_STATUS", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 30).Value = status;  
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_DOC_ISSUE_DATE", OracleDbType.Date).Value = pid;
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_EST_OBLG_DATE", OracleDbType.Date).Value = eod;
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_AMT_TO_APPLY", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = amtApply;
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_WBS", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 20).Value = wbs;
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_AMT1_TO_APPLY", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = 0;
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_AMT2_TO_APPLY", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = 0;
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_UPDATE_USER", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 50).Value =
user;             
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_DESC_WORK", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 50).Value = dow;
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_RET_CODE", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction =
ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_RET_MSG", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50).Direction =
ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I can run the procedure from Toad without any errors, the date format in Toad is '05-MAY-2012'. I get a "too many characters in character literal" error if I try and add a sigle qoute to the date value in the code-behind. Any assistance or direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: could you take a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515938/add-date-parameter-to-oracle-query) May be you're familiar with my issue.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend adding a DateTime .Net value (variable) and then assigning the parameter to the variable.  This will handle the conversion for you.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2012, 5, 7, 12, 23, 22, 0);
cmd.Parameters.Add(dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), OracleDbType.Date).Value = dt;
```

Comment: The format that works in Toad is '07-MAY-2011' but not in the code parameter value.

Comment: What does that have to do with the solution I gave you? Toad and ADO.net are two different things.  Did you try the option I gave you above?

Comment: Thanks for responding, yes I did try it was not successful with the same error. The format that is produced above 05/07/2012 00:00:00 also is not successful in the Toad environment for this procedure. I was mearly pointing out the successful format run in Toad for this procedure. My thought was if I could reproduce that format on the .net side it should work.

Comment: Try it without specifying the data type. I edited my answer to show.

Comment: I get a error as the "cmd.Parameters.Add("P_DOC_ISSUE_DATE").Value" defaults to an int type.

Comment: OK - one more change - the above should work for you (see edit).

Comment: question, how does the value get assigned to "P_DOC_ISSUE_DATE"

Comment: Sorry - left that off.  This just isn't my day.  :)

Comment: Solved: This is what I used "var pid = DateTime.ParseExact(e.RowData["PLAN_ISSUE_DATE"], "dd-MMM-yyyy", null);" then set the date parameter value to the "pid"

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

[OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx)

to guess which is the required data type and name for each parameter. Once you know that, you can modify your method accordingly.

Sometimes you get errors because the type you decided to use isn't the one expected by the database (i.e. for C# DateTime there can be TimeStamp, Date, SmallDate... depending on the DB kind. Using the wrong type for the paramter can cause errors or truncate data).

Never try to pass the values as strings. Pass them as the corresponding C# type. I.e. for passing dates, pass a DateTime object. The program will take care to convert it to a format which will be understood by the database. If you pass a string, unless it's a universal format, you can get into trouble if you change the DB config, i.e. the default language. That's why it's better of to let the system take care of the conversion details. It will always do it the right way.

Comment: I am not familar with this method, I need to read up on this, thanks