# Add date parameter to oracle query

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, oracle, oracle11g

What I'm trying to do is to execute the query between two dates, and the dates would come from a parameter.

In the below code, I'm putting one parameter and letting the second date as fixed just for example purposes.

The code / query is kind of long to paste it here, but here is a short version:

```
OracleParameter fromDateParameter = new OracleParameter();
fromDateParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
fromDateParameter.Value = "'3/06/2013 20:00:00'";

this.oracleDataAdapter4.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand("
   SELECT DISTINCT (LOG.RID) FROM LOG WHERE LOG.TIMESTAMP 
   BETWEEN TO_DATE(:fromDateParameter, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss ') 
   AND TO_DATE('3/06/2013 23:59:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss '))", 
   oracleConnection4);

oracleDataAdapter4.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(fromDateParameter);           
this.oracleDataAdapter4.Fill(event11);
```

And I got this message:

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was
>   expected

I did the same query without the parameter and it works just fine.

Thanks

Comment: WHERE = LOG.TIMESTAMP BETWEEN ... is that ok? shouldn't be some thing like WHERE LOG.TIMESTAMP BETWEEN  ...

Comment: ok, lets take the parameter off the equation SELECT DISTINCT (LOG.RID) FROM LOG WHERE = LOG.TIMESTAMP 
   BETWEEN TO_DATE('3/06/2013 23:59:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss ') 
   AND TO_DATE('3/06/2013 23:59:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss ') does it work?

Comment: If I replace `:fromDateParameter` for `'3/06/2013 20:00:00'` it works great.

Comment: ok... can you tell me exactly what is the value for :fromDateParameter  ? perhaps doesn't match with this format MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss

Comment: well, `TO_DATE` is converting to that specific format, it doesn't have to "match". You can see the value of `:fromDateParameter` in my code above. `fromDateParameter.Value = "'3/06/2013 20:00:00'";`

Comment: right.. "'3/06/2013 20:00:00'" did you try "3/06/2013 20:00:00" ? without the simple qouts '

Comment: Yes I did. Also an error.

Comment: Did you try to pass parameter of type Date?

Comment: perhaps is something in how are you adding the parameter:   oracleDataAdapter4.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(OracleParameter(":fromDateParameter", OracleType.DateTime));

Comment: I think your query is wrong:  LOG WHERE = LOG.TIMESTAMP - please, remove "="

Comment: @evgenyl I made a shorter version of the original query, so I did a typo there. But in the original there was not "=". So, the query was running great withou the parameter. Thanks for noticing it. Btw, I did try with "Date" type and same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do it using Varchar2 Datatype. So, I'm giving the answer using Date Datatype.

```
if (dateTo.Minute > 30)
   minToInt = 30;
else
   minToInt = 00;

dateFrom = DateTime.Now;
dateTo = DateTime.Now;     

DateTime dateFrom = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, dateFrom.Hour, 00, 00);
DateTime dateTo = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, dateTo.Hour, minToInt, 00);

////////FROM DATE/////////
OracleParameter fromDateParameter = new OracleParameter();
fromDateParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date;
fromDateParameter.Value = dateFrom;

////////TO DATE/////////
OracleParameter toDateParameter = new OracleParameter();
toDateParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date;
toDateParameter.Value = dateTo;


this.oracleDataAdapter4.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand("
   SELECT DISTINCT (LOG.RID) FROM LOG WHERE LOG.TIMESTAMP 
   BETWEEN :fromDateParameter 
   AND :toDateParameter)", oracleConnection4);

oracleDataAdapter4.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(fromDateParameter);           
oracleDataAdapter4.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(toDateParameter);  
this.oracleDataAdapter4.Fill(event11);
```

---

Don't get confuse with the if/else minute validation, it is just for my query purpose.

Comment: Mister, your second parameter shouldn't be "...AND :toDateParameter)", ?