# How to convert a string to DbType.Date in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I want to assign the text box input to the oracle db parameter of type date. So how do I convert from string to `DbType.Date` without using the `to_date()` function in the DB? I'm using the `System.Data.OracleClient` namespace. Here is my code

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("IN_SERIALNO", DbType.Date).Value = ?;
```

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime("date string");` did you try this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add date parameter to oracle query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515938/add-date-parameter-to-oracle-query)

Comment: what does your textbox string input looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse(date.Text); 
OracleParameter DateParameter = new OracleParameter();
DateParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date;
DateParameter.Value = dateValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("IN_SERIALNO", OracleType.DateTime)
```

**UPDATE**
I have tested this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("IN_SERIALNO", OracleType.DateTime).value = textBox1.Text;
```

I would like to note that I needed to use like, >=, or include the time to make this work.

Comment: Thank u the reply. But the "IN_SERIALNO" is Data type in DB.

Comment: This works only if your local NLS-Settings matches the date format you have in `textBox1.Text`. Passing a `DateTime` value is much more secure.